# How to see that ${(\mathbb Z}[x]/(x + 3))/(x^2+1) \cong {\mathbb Z}/(10)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

What do I need to look at in order to make it obvious for myself that ${(\mathbb Z}[x]/(x + 3))/(x^2+1) \cong {\mathbb Z}/(10)$? For now, I don't see a reason why these two rings should be isomorphic.

Comment: Are you sure these are the right rings? ${\mathbb Z}[x]/(x + 3) \cong \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @lhf Sure, but to make sense of $\mathbb{Z}/(x^2+1),$ we have to remember that the isomorphism you wrote identifies $x$ with $-3.$ So we get $\mathbb{Z}/((-3)^2+1),$ as desired. For whatever reason, I personally find this less intuitive than the answer I wrote, but it's perfectly good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of the quotient in the other order (not necessary, but somehow makes it more obvious to me). Then it looks like we took $\mathbb{Z},$ adjoined a square root of $-1,$ then decided that square root was actually just the element $-3.$ So in the end, all we've done is force $(-3)^2 = -1,$ or $10 = 0.$

Comment: Why the downvote? Let me emphasize that the question asks how to see the statement as *obvious*, not how to give a thorough proof.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\left(x+3,x^2+1\right)=\big(x+3,(x^2+1)-(x+3)(x-3)\big)$.

Comment: Do you mean $x^2+1= (x^2+1)-(x^2-9)$, so that $(x+3, x^2+1)=(x+3, 10)$? But then why is $(x+3,10)=(10)$?

Comment: @sequence: $(x+3, 10)$ is *not* $(10)$. But note the right hand side is $\mathbb{Z}/(10)$, not $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(10)$.

Comment: @Hurkyl If $(x+3, x^2+1)= (x+3, (x^2+1)-(x^2-9))$, then $(x+3, x^2+1)=(x+3, 10)$. How does it follow that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+3,10)\cong \mathbb{Z}/(10)$? This is the main thing I'm trying to get.

Comment: @Hurkyl I just edited my comment.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+3,10)\cong\big(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x+3)\big)/(10)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(10)$.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic modulo the congruence relation generated by $x+3$ is extremely simple: you have $x \equiv -3$ and you can reduce anything to a canonical representative simply by substituting $x \mapsto -3$.

In particular, $x^2 + 1 \equiv (-3)^3 + 1$

---

The simplest way to apply this observation algebraically is the observation that "evaluation at $-3$" is an isomorphism

$$\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x+3) \cong \mathbb{Z} $$

so that

$$ (\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x+3)) / (x^2 + 1)
\cong \mathbb{Z} / ((-3)^2 + 1) $$